# Icon for gnome system moniter does not scale in 18.04 Mate

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

This is really a bug report but if someone knows a workaround it would be great.
All other icons scale to the size of the panel when I move them there except for the icon for the Gnome System Monitor, it stays TINY.

Comment: Please check if **Gnome tweak tool** is installed? It can help check some installed extensions. Some extensions like **Dash to panel** overlap default icon size settings for Dash or Applications menu.

Comment: Did not find any option that would change icon scaling or size for that matter.

Comment: If you use Dash to panel, icons size can be changed in settings of extension -> Position and Style (tab) -> Panel Size. But again in case using extension. You dont answer to my comment - use it or not?

Comment: I can recommend to not to use GNOMEs Hell components on MATE. Just use `mate-system-monitor` instead.

Comment: Sorry, no I do not use Dash, but I have gnome-tweak installed. I am new to Mate and had not seen that there was a Mate system monitor. I will use that it is fine. Thanks for responding S_Flash and NOrbert.